# Не получается уменьшить размер раздела диска

Tags: linux, gparted

Я хочу уменьшить размер раздела `dev/sda5` через GParted
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня это не получается, кнопка `Resize` не активна. Ползунок так-же не получается передвинать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сижу на Clear Linux

Может кто-то подсказать в чем проблема и как исправить?

Comment: Раздел нужно предварительно отмонтировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для уменьшения раздела его нужно отмонтировать и проверить на ошибки полной проверкой. Корневой раздел во время работы компьютера отмонтировать нельзя.

Запишите live cd на флешку и с загрузочной флешки уменьшайте раздел.

Уменьшение раздела может занять продолжительное время.